# Ember.js renderTemplate new template inside index

Tags: ember.js

Can I have help with this?

This is the main idea 
i want a table with a link/button to create a new entry on click it will add a form in the first row of the table, the form is saved a template named posts/new and I want to load that template inside the posts/index, on save it will hide the template and update the table

currently I have two templates `posts/index` and `posts/new`
inside post/index I have `{{link-to 'posts.new'}}` and an `{{outlet newCell}}` inside `posts.index` and 
I want to display `posts.new` to the `newCell` on click with `{{link-to posts.new}}`

my current code displays `posts.new` inside `posts.index` immediately when `posts.index` is loaded,
but I only want it to happen when the `link-to` is clicked but doing so i really goes straight to `posts.new`

here is a trimmed down version of my 
**[code](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qawodala/6/edit)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your use case you should be using `Post` resource for the table display not `PostIndex`. And when redirecting to `post.new` add a empty row above. What you are trying to do is breaking the convention of resource and nested routes. Using the above approach it can be easily handled.

A sample is [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qawodala/9/edit)

Comment: thanks that's it.. been doing it the wrong way thanks